# Return values of operators

Tags: python, properties, operator

When calling an **operator** like `wm.link`, is there a way to get the **user input** like selected *directory*, *filepath* or *object name*?

Here is a simple code example:

```
import bpy

class appendObjectsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Replace Object"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_append"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        property = row.operator("wm.link")
        property.relative_path=True
        property.autoselect=True
        property.active_layer=True
        property.instance_groups=True        

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# register and unregister functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(appendObjectsPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(appendObjectsPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [API documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#operators-bpy-ops)

> Operators don’t have return values as you might expect, instead they return a set() which is made up of: {‘RUNNING_MODAL’, ‘CANCELLED’, ‘FINISHED’, ‘PASS_THROUGH’}. Common return values are {‘FINISHED’} and {‘CANCELLED’}.

You might get the arguments passed to a **registered** operator like this:

```
bpy.context.active_operator.properties['keyword']
```

or

```
bpy.context.window_manager.operators[-1].properties['keyword']
```

For more information about linking see also [BlendDataLibraries](http://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#module-bpy.types) and [Library](http://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Library.html#module-bpy.types).

Comment: `wm.link` doesn't appear in the info area so it is not being registered. I don't think it is possible.