# Get filepath of appended object

Tags: python, scripting, append

Is it possible to get the filepath of a .blend where from we append an object to store it in a StringProperty ?

Comment: appended or linked? Linked data stores the location of the file it belongs to while appended objects leaves no trace. You may be able to get it if your operator controls the append process.

Comment: probably related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/return-values-of-higher-ui-functions As sambler says, unfortunately you need to write a custom append operator to return the path.

Comment: If the link allows me to have my filepath, I shall manage with, thank you very much.